# IE9 navigation links over image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I am struggling for days to implemnet an image gallery for my site. I like the prev next buttons styles that fancybox uses.

I have my image template at: http://www.rochiidevis.com/gallery_test/gallery.html

The problem is that my example does not work on ie9 ... actually in ie the images are behind the image. Can you help me correcting the example that when I hover the mouse over image to have the prev next arrows ... as I have them in chrome or firefox.

Many many thanks, 
Radu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add DOCTYPE at begin of your page before `<html>` tag, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```